How do two atomic orbitals make two molecular orbitals?
Suppose there are two s atomic orbitals. If they combine in phase , bonding MO is formed and if they combine out of phase , antibonding MO is formed. But at a time , either the orbitals will combine in phase or out of phase , giving either bonding MO or antibonding MO. But everywhere, it's said that both BMO and ABMO is formed. How is this possible ? If the orbitals are busy in holding each other in phase , how can they combine out of phase at same time simultaneously ?
Context : I don't know quantum mechanics. I don't even understand what phases of an orbital actually mean physically. But in chemistry classes , it's necessary to memorise these stuffs without understanding it with any rigour or reasons.
Please explain in simple language.
Acronyms :
BMO : Bonding Molecular orbital
ABMO: Anti BMO


How do two atomic orbitals make two molecular orbitals?


Context : I don't know quantum mechanics.

Uh oh...

I don't even understand what phases of an orbital actually mean physically.

Double uh oh...

In this context, the word "phase" means a complex number with magnitude one. For example, the numbers $1$, $i$, $-1$, and $-i$ are all different "phases," since they all have an absolute square of 1.
(Sometimes in physics and mathematics, the word "phase" can mean different things too though, so be careful.)

Atomic orbitals are functions of space that are usually taken as eigenfunctions of some "atomic" hamiltonian. But never mind that.
Suppose you have two atomic orbitals. Call them:
$$
f(\vec r)
$$
and
$$
g(\vec r)\;.
$$
The "molecular" orbitals are just weighted sums of the atomic orbital. So, for example, one molecular orbital could be
$$
a(\vec r) = f(\vec r) + g(\vec r)\;.\tag{1}
$$
And another could be:
$$
b(\vec r) = f(\vec r) - g(\vec r)\;.\tag{2}
$$
See how there is a relative "phase" difference between the molecular orbital $a$ in Eq. (1) and the molecular orbital $b$ in Eq. (2)? That makes these two molecular orbitals "orthogonal." And so those two molecular orbital are just as good a basis at the original two atomic orbitals.
Thus, we have formed two molecular orbitals ($a$ and $b$) out of two atomic orbitals ($f$ and $g$).

I don't have the mathematical background used in this answer. I just passed school recently. If understanding orbitals etc requires these mathematics , why do they teach us these stuffs superficially ?

I just want to know that if two orbitals in phase combine , they are busy in doing so. How can they at the same time combine out of phase ?

"why do they teach us...?" I have no idea who you are and I have no idea who "they" are, my man. Better open up a math book.

Lets consider Water Waves
In-Phase Combination (Bonding MO):
Imagine you have two pebbles, and you drop them into a still pond at the same time, close to each other.
As the ripples (waves) from each pebble spread out, they meet.
If the crests (the high points) and troughs (the low points) of the waves line up, they add together, creating a bigger wave.
This represents the bonding molecular orbital (BMO), where the two atomic orbitals combine constructively, resulting in a stable, lower-energy orbital.
Out-of-Phase Combination (Antibonding MO):
Now imagine you drop the pebbles in such a way that the crest of one wave meets the trough of the other wave.
When these out-of-phase waves meet, they cancel each other out, either partially or completely, creating a smaller wave or even a flat surface where the waves meet.
This represents the antibonding molecular orbital (ABMO), where the two atomic orbitals combine destructively, leading to a less stable, higher-energy orbital.
Whenever you drop the pebbles, both the in-phase (constructive) and out-of-phase (destructive) interactions happen at the same time in different parts of the pond.
Similarly, when atomic orbitals combine, the electrons in those orbitals can occupy both the bonding and antibonding orbitals, so both BMOs and ABMOs are formed simultaneously.

I don't know if it'sa correct or incorrect analogy. So.I can't say anything

thats simply the explanation of interference , so, the creation of BMOs and ABMOs can be thought of as the result of wave interference patterns—constructive interference leading to bonding and destructive interference leading to antibonding.

if you have no physics knowledge , kindly google about single slit , double slit interference , get the logic there first

I have studied till high school physics except wave mechanics.

an experimental approach buddy I hope this helps you :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iuv6hY6zsd0

there after its up to your imagination , how much you cancel the odds and add up the missing ones :)
